# Python absolute/relative importing between different directory hierarchy

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-import

I have the following file structure for my project:

```
    /myApp
        __init__.py
        main.py
            /package1
                __init__.py
                moduleA.py
            /package2
                __init__.py
                moduleB.py
```

I am running myApp/main.py in the interpreter, this should be at the top directory of my project.
I checked `__name__ == '__main__'` and it returns 'True'. I also checked that the top level directory is in the os.path.

In the main.py I tried to call `from .package1 import moduleA` but it raise an error:
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

I then tried to use absolute importing `from myApp.package1 import moduleA` but it raise an error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myApp'`

However, if I instead call `from package1 import moduleA` the package is imported fine.

Then, in package1/moduleA.py I tried to call `from ..package2 import moduleB` but it raise an error:
`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. Please note that I am NOT running the package1/moduleA.py in the interpreter but instead it was imported into main.py as a module. I checked that `__name__ == '__main__'` is False for the moduleA.py being imported.

I essentially have the following questions:

1. With the top level directory in the os.path why it is not able to recognizes 'myApp'? It is then impossible to use any absolute import?
2. With the **init**.py file in the top level directory it should be recognized as a package but why can't I use relative import `from .package1 import moduleA` in main.py?
3. Calling `from package1 import moduleA` in main.py would allow me to successfully import moduleA. But if I try to call `from ..package2 import moduleB` in moduleA.py the beyond top level error is raised. Again I am not running the package itself but instead it is imported into main.py so the interpreter should be able to recognize where the top level directory is?

I have been searching the web for a while and it unable to figure out how to properly use absolute and relative import in a project with multiple levels of directory. Most of the answers focuses on the issue that that python is unable to locate the top level directory if a module in the sub-package is run directly by the interpreter, or the top level directory is not in os.path. However, both are not the case in my problem.

Comment: If directory "myApp" is in `sys.path`, "myApp" itself is not recognized as package (even with a `__init__.py` file), only directories in it are. Relative imports relating to it can't work because these imports have to relate to packages.

Comment: Absolute imports are relative to the directories in `sys.path`, meaning they start **in** these directories, not above.

Comment: By the way: The directory containing the main script is automatically added to `sys.path`, you don't have to add it manually.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Butscher, but do you know why should `from ..package2 import moduleB` in moduleA.py raise an `attempted relative import beyond top-level package` error when imported into main.py?

Comment: The `..` points to the "package" `myApp` which isn't a package, so it isn't allowed. `top-level package` in the error means here `package1` (maybe a bit misleading).

Comment: @Michael Butscher Thanks, I added one more level of directory to contain all the packages and put the main.py outside and it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the parent directory of `myApp` then run main as

```
$ python -m myApp.main # note no .py
```

The `-m` switch run it as a module of the myApp parent package. You should not add myApp to the sys.path.